# Restrict input string with the help of html pattern

Tags: regex, html

I want to add disallow user to submit form if the user input contains 'xyz.co.in' in the input fields but this should be done with html5 pattern, I do not want to do it with jquery or javacript. Can anyone please help me with what should be its respective pattern, I mean what should go in pattern field in `<input type='text' pattern='<some pattern goes here>'/>`

So that user can insert anything in the input field except `xyz.co.in`.

**UPDATE**

Here is what I have so far:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>disallow a pattern</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" >
            <input type="text" pattern="^(?!.*\bxyz\.co\.in\b)" />
            <input type="submit" name="Go1" value="Go"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, you shared with us what you need. Now, please let us know where you got stuck.

Comment: @stribizhev I think I dint understand what you are asking for but still let me try to explain, Actually I know home to apply patters to define the acceptable strings I mean I know how to write a pattern to define that my input field should have at least 3 words or start with so and so string but I do not know how to restrict user if he enters so and so string anywhere in the string. Does it answers your question?

Comment: Good, please add the code you have written so far to your question.

Comment: Well I havent written anything Actually I do not know what to write neither I find any site explaining how to write patterns to disallow a string in pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disallowing some string to be inside a larger string can be done with a [negative look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) anchored at the beginning.

Here is an example that disallows `xyz.co.in` in an input string:

```
^(?!.*xyz\.co\.in).*
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eV5zE8/3)

If you want to allow `mmmxyz.co.inmmmm` in the input string, [add word boundaries `\b` around the word](https://regex101.com/r/eV5zE8/4).

Note that `pattern` attribute value is anchored by default, so `^` might not be necessary, and `.*` is necessary to ensure the entire string is matched.

**UPDATE**

To disallow input of `xyz.co.in` and allow any other, use

```
^(?!xyz\.co\.in$).*
```

Comment: it does not allow me to enter anything have a look at http://jsbin.com/zuwiqijafu/edit?html,output

Comment: Ah yes, it expects the whole string match. Add `.*` at the end.

Comment: But I want something like user can enter anything except xyz.co.in

Comment: P.S. could you please remove the -1 from my question

Comment: I can only give you +1, as that minus is not mine. Does my solution work for you?